# FetchError: invalid json response body reason: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 - nextjs

Tags: wordpress, next.js

I am using `getStaticProps` and `getStaticPaths`, I used fetch API to call an API endpoint (which is Wordpress headless CMS in my case) and set the paths for dynamic routing. When I run `npm dev` it works fine, the data is fetched correctly. But at build time it gives error that:

> FetchError: invalid json response body at https://abr.af/wp/wp-json/wp/v2/advisors reason: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

My code in `pages/advisor/[advisor].js`

```
export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
  const advisors = await getAdvisors()
  const paths = advisors.map((each) => {
    return {
      params: { advisor: each.slug },
    }
  })

  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false,
  }
}

export const getStaticProps = async ({ params }) => {
  const query = params.advisor
  const advisors = await getAdvisors()
  const advisor = advisors.find((advisor) => advisor.slug === query)
  return {
    props: {
      advisor,
    },
  }
}
```

my fetch function in `component/FetchData.js`

```
export async function getAdvisors() {
  const res = await fetch('https://abr.af/wp/wp-json/wp/v2/advisors', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      // update with your user-agent
      'User-Agent': '*',
      Accept: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    },
  })
  const advisors = await res.json()

  return advisors
}

export async function getExpertise() {
  const res = await fetch('https://abr.af/wp/wp-json/wp/v2/expertise', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      // update with your user-agent
      'User-Agent': '*',
      Accept: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    },
  })
  const expertise = await res.json()

  return expertise
}
```

I googled this issue and find that I should add User-Agent header to my request but this not solve my problem.

I am new to Next.js, I don't know what is the reason any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, and had to switch to `getServerSideProps`. For my case, the api I was using was a next api that was not readily available during build time (db connection + fetching).

I had to go back to [NextJS documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#when-should-i-use-getstaticprops), to understand when you should use `getStaticProps`.

And this is what is stated:

> - The data required to render the page is available at build time ahead
>   of a user’s request.
> - The data comes from a headless CMS.
> - The data can
>   be publicly cached (not user-specific).
> - The page must be pre-rendered
>   (for SEO) and be very fast — getStaticProps generates HTML and JSON
>   files, both of which can be cached by a CDN for performance.

Comment: I clean install WordPress and now it works.