# SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 NEXTJS dynamic routing

Tags: next.js, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I am getting this error and I am not able to figure out the cause.

code:

[This is my code, please review](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JLsK.png)

Tried to do some dynamic routing, expected to get an output rather I got this error

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: add code in text-format.

Answer (score 0):

Send your browser to the localhost address and see what the json looks like. I imagine the localhost:3000/api/hello + id endpoint is failing to return valid JSON.

also, looks like [FetchError: invalid json response body reason: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 - nextjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66434076/fetcherror-invalid-json-response-body-reason-unexpected-token-in-json-at-pos)